# In John 5:18, shouldn't there be scare quote punctuation marks to identify the Jews' false accusations against Jesus?

Tags: john, christology, sabbath, jews

John 5:18 according to the ESV:

> This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because
> not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his
> own Father, making himself equal with God.

Translation proposal with the proper scare quote punctuation marks added:

> This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only was he "breaking the Sabbath," but he was even calling God his
> own Father, "making himself equal with God."

Seeing that Jesus never sinned and therefore never violated the 4th commandment by breaking a Sabbath, and that Jesus is not equal with God which would violate the 1st commandment, wouldn't these be false accusations lifted against Jesus, thereby requiring the need of scare quote punctuation marks?

In the following verse, Jesus seems to be reinforcing the idea that he is not equal with God, but that whatever his Father does, he does. And that he cannot do anything on his own, but only with his power of his Father God.

**UPDATE**: After intense examination, I discovered that depending on the context, `ἴσον` can actually be rendered not just as "equal", but also as "*to be similar*" or "*to be like*". Could this be what the author was originally intending to convey?

And then it came suddenly to me. Could this passage be saying that the Jews were upset that Jesus was calling God his own Father, "making himself out *to be like* God, instead of that Jesus was making himself equal with God?

Because of this, I posted a new follow-up question here: [In John 5:18 and John 10:33, could the final Greek words be translated as, "like God" and "a god", instead of "equal with God" and "yourself God"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/91498/62615)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151659/discussion-on-question-by-joshua-b-in-john-518-shouldnt-there-be-scare-quote); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no quotes in the Greek text - either here or anywhere else in the NT. But some translators do go out of their way to make sure readers understand the Bible itself is not teaching that Jesus broke the Sabbath etc. For example:

- AMP - ...not only was He breaking the Sabbath [from their viewpoint], but He was also calling God His own Father, making Himself equal with God.
- ICB - They said, “First Jesus was breaking the law about the Sabbath day. Then he said that God is his own Father! He is making himself equal with God!”
- ERV - They thought it was bad enough that he was breaking the law about the Sabbath day. And now he was saying that God is his Father, making himself equal with God!

These translations take liberties with the text. Of the three, the AMP version is preferable because it transparently brackets its editorial gloss rather than making it a part of the translated text. The fact that these were accusations against Jesus rather than facts is easily inferred by the reader and there is no reason to adjust the translation.

Comment: If one really believes Jesus, his statements should suffice. He plainly said his Father is greater than all.

Comment: +1. Simple and concise. I think that last sentence could even be bolded.

Comment: @Jason_, do you think that adding punctuation around the accusations would sharpen the current translation without changing any of it?

Comment: Just made a breakthrough an hour ago. The Greek word used to render "equal with" is a translator's bias. The word ἴσον can also be used to mean "to be like" or "to be similar"!

Answer (score 0):

[Scare Quotes](https://www.wordnik.com/words/scare%20quotes)

> noun plural: 1. Quotation marks used to emphasize a word or phrase or to
> indicate its special status, especially to express doubt about its
> validity or to criticize its use.

In John 5:18, the accusations made by the Jews against Jesus are not presented in scare quotes in translations because **the passage is recounting the perspective of the Jews rather than offering a commentary on the validity of their accusations.** This helps keep bias out of the scripture.

The question of course isn't, *could* a translator add scare quotes, but *should* a translator add scare quotes.

Here's the verse with scare quotes added: ESV

> "This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because
> not only was he 'breaking the Sabbath,' but he was even 'calling God
> his own Father, making himself equal with God.'"

By adding scare quotes, we are adding a way that we wish the verse to be interpreted. That being said, it adds a layer of confusion as

- people would have to understand the usage of scare quotes
- it may introduce ambiguity and confusion rather than clarity
- adding scare quotes would alter the original text and would be seen as imposing an interpretation on the scripture that goes beyond what is explicitly stated. For translators, it is important to preserve the integrity of the text and allow readers to draw their own conclusions based on context and interpretation. Which is a good reason to have this site.
- while the accusations against Jesus may be false, it's essential to approach the text with *exegetical caution* and avoid imposing *modern punctuation* conventions. Why? Because that may not accurately reflect the original intent of the author.

Comment: I think this is the only place in the whole of scripture that I know where scare quotes would be quite useful and advantageous. Why? Because this verse is so massively taken out of context by Trinitarians to promote their theory that Jesus is equal with God. Without the "scare quotes", the context is more foggy to the reader, and mistakes can be made without the context being clearly punctuated among everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Jews saw that He was indeed breaking the Sabbath by putting Himself above Sabbath through the Lordly words “Son of the Man is the Lord of the Sabbath” (Matthew 12:8), now, the Lord is not subject to of what He is the Lord. But who can be above Sabbath as to treat it at will? A man? - No. An angel? - even more, No. Remains that those words could be said only by Father, or by someone with equal divine authority with the Father. Thus, Jews are right with this account: He breaks Sabbath, being its Lord and establisher.

Ritualistic keeping of Sabbath, like Jews practiced it then and practice also now, sometimes even coming to bizarre extremities like not pushing buttons of elevator on Sabbath, considering it to be a violation of the commandment, is thus broken by Christ, and can be and must be obsolete with His advent. Moreover, who continues keeping Sabbath in such a way after the advent of Christ, who made it obsolete, he has abolished the Cross and has fallen from grace (cf. Galatians 5:4).

The same in the case of the Sonship of Christ: Jews very correctly understand that the Lord called God His Father in a drastically different sense than when the same Jews called God their Father (John 8:41): in their case they saw no blasphemy, for they did not imply that they were of the same essence with the Father, which would be a blasphemy; however, in Christ's saying they saw exactly this blasphemy, and Christ indeed implied this very thing, even demanding for that reason the equal honor with the Father (John 5:23). Had any highest angel, be it Raphael, Gabriel or Michael not only demanded, but even remotely suggested the equal honor with the Father, this angel would have been immediately expelled from the heavenly ranks and adjoined to the demonic ranks for such a stupid ontological mistake and arrogance.

Comment: That's absolutely wrong. Jesus never broke the Sabbath, as he is sinless. Breaking the Sabbath would constitute him violating the 4th commandment, which certainly did not do. As the Lord of the Sabbath, Jesus became the Sabbath itself by becoming our rest and restoring the broken hearted, which did not violate any commandment and in fact kept it to the full. Jesus as the fulfillment of the Sabbath is our spiritual rest at all times, where we never work sin in him, but righteousness in the Spirit of God. And finally Jesus is not equal with God, otherwise the headship would be violated.

Comment: @JoshuaB He established the Sabbath and He can also abolish the Sabbath as its Lord and establisher. Ritualistic Sabbath-keeping is a part of the Law that has power only till the advent of Christ, after which it can be and must be obsolete (cf. Luke 16:16, Romans 7:3-4).

Comment: @JoshuaB "And finally Jesus is not equal with God, otherwise the headship would be violated" - What?! Headship of the Father is never violated in correct theology! Father is the Source in the Trinity, He gives birth to the Son and He issues the H. Ghost. But this never forfeits the equality of both Son and the H. Ghost with their only Source - the Father, because when Father naturally and eternally gives birth to the Son, He gives to the Son His (Father's) entire essence, so the Son is also 100% God in His essence, deserving the same worship as Father, and the same holds with the H. Ghost.

Comment: @JoshuaB P.S. and I have 0 concern about your down-votings, but the correct rendering of the Scripture, which you twist and skew by your Arian bias, quite unfortunately

Comment: Arius was a quasi-Unitarian in that he did hold to certain aspects of trinitarian theology. Contrary to Arius, I'm a full Unitarian who holds absolutely no aspects of trinitarian theology and christology, other than that Jesus was created in the image of his Father, has been given authority and judgement by his Father, and was given the Name above all names which is God the Father's Name: YHWH (Yahuah)

Comment: @JoshuaB Impossible, ontologically, for Father to create anything without the necessary Instrument for creation - the Logos. To say that Father first - hell only knows by what means - creates Logos and then through Logos creates rest of the world is weird, for if Logos is not ontologically necessary for Him to create the world, then He, being allmighty, can, in principle, create the world without Logos also; but since this is preposterous, then we can only assume that Logos is ontologically necessary for Father to create, if so, then necessarily uncreated and as such Logos is co-Creator, God.

Answer (score 0):

Let us examine the verse

John 5:18 according to the ESV:

This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.

First, the Greek word that was translated as breaking here does not mean breaking. Bible hub shows it as to "loosen". So with the word "elyen" meaning to "loosen", did Jesus really break the law which he said cannot be broken John 10:35?

John 10:35 Literal Standard Version

If He called them gods to whom the word of God came (and the Writing is not able to be broken),

Jesus response to the accusation also reveal that, King David himself ate food in God’s Temple – food that a person who is not a priest is not allowed to eat. He also reminded the Pharisees that, some of the priest profane the temple on the Sabbath day and yet are innocent. Thus, Jesus showed that the sufferings of man rank higher than the Sabbath.

ἔλυεν (elyen)
Verb - Imperfect Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 3089: A primary verb; to 'loosen'.

Now for the other part of the verse in question.

but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.

Does John or any apostle show that if anyone calls God his Father, he is claiming to be equal with God! Even Jesus' accusers call God their Father. John 8:41. Jesus tells his followers to call God their Father. Luke 3:38. Anyone calling God their Father does not mean they are claiming to be equal with God. The allegation that calling God is claiming to be equal with God has no support from the patriarchs, prophets and apostles. The allegation must have come from those who by their tradition nullify God's word. Thus, a teaching that assent to this false allegation is basing their teaching on the words of Jesus accusers, not on Jesus or his followers or God.

Examining the word equal (ison) in Matthew 20:12 and Luke 20:36, we find the workers Matthew 20:12 are equal only in the amount of money they were paid. In Luke 20:36 angels and resurrected humans are equal in terms of not dying only. They are not equal in essence.

Luke 20:36 ASV

for neither can they die any more: for they are equal unto the angels; and are sons of God, being sons of the resurrection

Jesus' response to the accusation in John 5:19 shows the that he was not God and he did not claim to be   God.

John 5:19 ASV

Jesus therefore answered and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father doing: for what things soever he doeth, these the Son also doeth in like manner.

Consider Matthew 26:39 too where Jesus had to choose the Father's will instead of his.

Matthew 26:39 ASV

And he went forward a little, and fell on his face, and prayed, saying, My Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass away from me: nevertheless, not as I will, but as thou wilt.

But God who does whatever pleases him.

Psalm 115:3 ASV

But our God is in the heavens: He hath done whatsoever he pleased.

Even without the "
scare quote punctuation marks to identify the Jews' false accusations against Jesus". It is clear from Jesus own words that he did not claim to be equal to his God.
Aligning with Jesus' accusers to support a teaching that is not in the bible is delusive. The bible does not teach that one is claiming to be equal to God if one calls God his Father. Jesus statement about "the Father is greater than I" and greater than all in John 14:28-29 answers the question about being equal to God clearly.

Comment: Cannot argue with anything that you have said here. You pretty much nailed it. It's an upvote from me at least.