# In John 5:18 should ἴσον be translated as "equal with" or "like"?

Tags: greek, john, christology

John 5:18 according to the ESV:

> This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because
> not only was he breaking the Sabbath,
>
> but he was even calling God his own Father, **making himself *equal with* God**.

But I want to propose that ἴσον should instead be translated as "like", as in "to be similar to":

> This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because
> not only was he breaking the Sabbath,
>
> but he was even calling God his own Father, **making himself *like* God**.

Is this a valid translation of the Greek?

Comment: I think if you cut this question back to just being about the meaning and translation of ἴσον in John 5:18 it would be a fine question. Your implications may not may not be reasonable, but they don't belong in the question. The issue about the article also should be a distinct question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I just took your advice and cut back the question by removing my additional notes under the text. Let's reopen this post.

Comment: @JoshuaB John 10:18 doesn't have ἴσον - it's an entirely unrelated question, and if you want to ask about it you need to do so in a new question. I've edited your question and reopened it, but you really need to edit it further to add some reason for thinking "like" is a valid translation, for example, did you see that in a Greek dictionary? Otherwise you are likely to get lots of downvotes for asking an unmotivated question.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that Greek is the origin of logic and this is one of the words well-used, whose meaning is quite precise.

In John 5:18, the operative word is ἴσος (isos) which means "equal, equivalent, identical" (Thayer).

The meaning of this word is **NOT** that of other words such as:

- ὅμοιος = like, similar to, resembling, of equal rank
- ὁμοιότης = likeness, resemblance.
- ὁμοιόω = I make like, liken; I compare.
- ὁμοίωμα = a likeness, or rather: form; a similitude
- ὁμοίως = in like manner, similarly, in the same way

Thus, Jesus was accused (correctly) of claiming that He was EQUAL with God, not similar to God, but **equal** to God.  That is, the OP's proposal is not linguistically possible.

**Articular vs Inarticular**

The OP also asks about whether "God" should be translated as "God" (with capital "G") or as "a god".  The answer is definitely the former because in both instances of the noun θεός, it is preceded by the article; this it literally read "the God".

In this case, the article means (according to Wallace in his Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics) the noun θεός is monadic - ie, unique.  "a god" would imply many gods which NT theology is vehemently opposed to.  Mark 12:29, 2 Tim 2:5, 1 Cor 8:4, 6, etc.

Comment: This is far more intellectually satisfying and logical and academically supportable than the convoluted argument being suggested. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Read the last half of this riveting article by David Hart on Philippians 2:6: https://ibb.co/WBRHRyv

Comment: @JoshuaB I strongly suggest you read the "riveting" testimony of the Jews at John 10:30 when Jesus literally said, "I and My Father WE are one." Vs33, "For a good work we do not stone You, but for blasphemy, and because You being a man, make YOURSELF OUT GOD." Notice it does not say "like God" or "a god," but God. Your so intent on denying the clear Deity of Jesus Christ that you have to add or put words like "like" in the text to change the explicit meaning? Btw, if you want to discuss Philippians 2:6 start another thread and we can discuss that as well.

Comment: The Jews actually said, "You being a man, make YOURSELF OUT **LIKE** GOD". Ison in Greek comes from the term of "isosceles" or level line. Depending on the context, this certainly does not only mean, "to be equal" in the sense of having the same rank, but also of having a similar nature or "like nature". I believe the Jews were not claiming Jesus to be literally God himself, but to be a divine elohim "god" creature from heaven, on similar or "like" footing with God - being God's only begotten Son.

Comment: @JoshuaB - see my answer - "like" would have been another.  "Equal is the correct and only translation.  Isosceles means equal length !!

Comment: Yes, it means equal length length, but the context can also mean "of like nature"!! Rendering the term "equal" takes it even further, saying that Jesus is of equal rank with the Eternal One, the Only God.

Comment: @JoshuaB - then I suggest you write your own authoritative lexicon.

Answer (score 2):

John 5:18 (ESV)

> This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.
> `διὰ τοῦτο οὖν μᾶλλον ἐζήτουν αὐτὸν οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι ἀποκτεῖναι ὅτι οὐ μόνον ἔλυεν τὸ σάββατον ἀλλὰ καὶ πατέρα ἴδιον ἔλεγεν τὸν θεόν ἴσον ἑαυτὸν ποιῶν τῷ θεῷ` [mGNT]

First, both times God is used with the article. The proper understanding of the explanatory statement added by John is *He was even calling **the** God His own Father, making Himself equal to **the** God* and for this reason the Jews sought to kill Him. The OP's suggestion, which ignores the meaning of `ἴσον` should be *making Himself out to be like **the** God*. Even if this was the meaning the Jews had, it is unlikely it would not be taken as a claim of equality with God.

Second, the verse is an explanation added by John. It is **John's** understanding of the reasons why they wanted Jesus dead. If the Jews were wrong, John would be obligated to explain they misunderstood Jesus. In fact, it is common for John to use misunderstanding to correct and advance a theme. In this case, it is John who introduces the theme which he does not correct.

Third, the first part of statement, *calling the God His own Father*, means *Son of God* is a statement the Jews understood as making Him equal with God. Much of the analysis on statements of deity use anachronistic standards. A contemporary examination excludes "Son of God" passages. Why? Because "Son of God" by definition does not mean equality with God. It is most unlikely anyone living in the first century (who was not an atheist) hearing someone say they are the Son of God would think "They are not claiming to be God." Quite the opposite, as John 5:18 says, when Jesus claimed to be the Son of God, He was making Himself equal with the God.

Comment: Equal only in the sense of being a deity from above and therefore like The Deity, not that Jesus is *equal* to The Deity in a sense of Jesus being God, but of the nature of who he is as *a god*: the Son of God. Jesus was being accused correctly of making himself *LIKE GOD*, not for making himself *equal with God* in the sense of literally being The God himself!

Comment: @JoshuaB I understand you position which disregards the actual text in order to support a preconceived doctrine. So I have nothing to add. The text is clear 5:18 is **the God** in both places.